# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of shared memory

Tags: java, postgresql

I am calling a function having more than 200 DROP Table Statements using JAVA and I am getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of shared memory.
What approach should i follow in order to avoid out of shared memomry ?

PS : Restriction is that I can't change any parameters related to PostgresSQL.

Comment: By "function" you mean a server side function or a Java method? Is the _cause_ of the exception on the server-side or on the client-side? Your little information bits don't provide enough information even for guessing.

Comment: By Function I mean a PostgresSQL Function(Procedure). The exception is at the end from where i am calling the function that is on the JAVA Side.

Answer (score 1):

If the cause of the error is on the server side: In PostgreSQL a function is always executed inside a transaction. `DO` blocks are anonymous functions and are handled the same way. And because even DML commands like `CREATE` or `DROP` are transactional in PostgreSQL, these commands also stress the usual resources used for `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT`.

My guess is that dropping a huge number of large tables eats to much memory. 
So if you don't need transactional behaviour in your function, the easiest way is to split the large function into several smaller ones. Call each function in a separate transaction.